# Can't get the menu bar to scale to screen size

Tags: css, navigation, alignment

I am trying to scale a menu bar according to screen size.  I've tried `float`, `@media` etc. but it hasn't worked properly. Full screen on my 13' looks great. However, as soon as I scale it down, the menu bar shifts to the right, but the page elements are fine. Menu is at the bottom `#navsite`.

CSS

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html{
    min-width:770px;
}

body{
    background:white url(candy/background.png) 0 0 repeat;
text-align:center;
}


/*=====[ Set up container divs and add background tiles ]=====*/

#pageheadContainer,
#contentContainer,
#footContainer{
width:100%;
}

#pageheadContainer{
    background:transparent url(candy/pageheadBackground.png) 0 100% repeat-x;
}

#contentContainer{
    background:#F7F7F7 url(candy/contentBackground2.png) 50% 100% repeat-y;
    float:left;
}

#footContainer{
    background:transparent url(candy/footBackground.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
    clear:both;
}

#pagehead,
#content,
#foot{
    width:770px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
text-align:left;
}


#pagehead{
    height:130px;
}

#foot{
    height:150px;
}

#pagehead{
    background:transparent url(candy/pageheadBackground2.png) 0 100% no-repeat;
}

#content{
    background:transparent url(candy/contentBackground.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    min-height:300px;
    _height:300px;
}

#foot{
    background:transparent url(candy/footBackground2.png) 100% 0 repeat-x;
}

#article{
    width:450px;
    float:left;
    padding:40px 0 20px 0;
    margin-left:25px;
}

#subContent{
    display:inline;
    width:180px;
    float:left;
    padding:25px 0 20px 0;
    margin-left:30px;
    color:#8B725A;
    font-size:.9em;
}


#foot ul{
    position:absolute;
    top:45px;
}

#foot li{
list-style-type:none;
}

#foot #foot1{
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:300px;
}

#foot #foot2{
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:570px;
}

#foot #pageTop{
    position:absolute;
    left:482px;
    top:-40px;
}

#foot #pageTop a{
    display:block;
    width:26px;
    height:26px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:transparent url(candy/pageTop.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    float:left;
}


body{
    font:normal 62.5%/1.8em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#content ul{
    margin:0.8em 0 0.6em 1em;
    padding-left:1em;
    list-style-type:square;
}

ol{
    margin:0.8em 0 0.6em 2em;
    padding-left:1em;
    list-style-type:lower-roman;
}

blockquote{
    margin:0.8em 0 0.6em 1em;
    padding-left:1em;
    font-style:italic;
    border-left:4px solid #E2D7CF;
} 

img{
    padding:2px;
    border:1px solid #F2F2F2;
} 

#content{
    font-size:1.25em;
}

p{
    margin:0.3em 0 0.6em 0;
}

a{
    color:#9D6141;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
} 

a:hover{
    background:#9D6141;
    color:#FFE;
}

#article{
    line-height:1.7em;
    color:#635141;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4{
 font-family:Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;
}

h2{
    color:#98533B;
    margin-bottom:.5em;
    line-height:1.7em;
    font-size:1.7em;
}

h3{
    margin:0.8em 0 0.6em 0;
    font-size:1.3em;
} 

h4{
    margin:0.8em 0 0.6em 0;
    font-size:1.1em;
} 


#subContent h2{
    font-size:1.3em;
}

#subContent h3{
    font-size:1.1em;
}


/*  menu navigation */
.navsite {width: 845px; height: 35px;  z-index: 100; 
margin-bottom: 3px; margin-left: 155px;}    

/* menu bar */

#headermenu {width: 800px; height: 35px;  z-index: 100;  position: absolute}

#headermenu ul {          
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: small;

}


#headermenu a {
    display: block;
    width: 8em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.3em;
    white-space: nowrap;

}

#headermenu li {         
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    width: 8em;                    
    background-color: #B67357;          /* medium brown */  
}
#headermenu li ul {               /* second level lists */
position: absolute;
    z-index:500;
    left: -999em;
    height: auto;
    width: 8em;
    border-width: 0.25em;
    margin: 0;     
}

#headermenu li:hover ul, #nav li.shfhover ul {   
    left: auto;
    z-index:100;
}

#content {
    clear: left;
    color: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 770px)
{
  #headermenu {
    width:770px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;}
}
```

Comment: Please put your relevant code within a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: can you provide some html code too? or as @Adrift said before, [jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be even better.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about not following the standards here, this is my first post.  Anyway, here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ESXJH/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is you're absolutely positioning the menu from the left of the browser. So when you resize it it moves.

If you want the whole site to be centered but fluid you can use the following

```
width:100%; max-width:400px; margin:auto;
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GG95g/)

Comment: Thanks AndrewHipp!  If I go this route, should I remove the positioning from all of the elements and let the wrapper statement control it?  My initial thought is yes but ...

Comment: Yes you can just put your content in the wrapper. You could also apply the same css to the header content and wrapper individually if you had a case where you needed them to not have a parent element